# Multiple relationship for multiple tax_query in WP_Query

Tags: wp-query, tax-query

I want to use the `WP_Query()` class to filter some of my posts. The problem I am facing now is handling the taxonomy query. Normally, the `WP_Query()` only handle one relationship for `tax_query()` (either AND or OR), but what I need is mixed use of these relationships on the `tax_query()`, how can achieve it?
eg

```
'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'taxonomy1',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( $term )
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'taxonomy3',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( $term3 ),
            'operator' => 'IN',
        )
       // below i want to use OR relationship
       'relation' => 'OR',
      array(
            'taxonomy' => 'taxonomy4',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( $term4 )
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'taxonomy2',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( $term2 ),
            'operator' => 'IN',
        )
    )
```

I know the code above is not working, do I need to use `WP_Query()` filter to do it? Any idea?

Answer (score 16):

This can be done by using the term_taxonomy_id rather than the slug, which will effectively ignore whichever taxonomy is specified and just look at the unique term_taxonomy_id field. This will allow you to effectively be able to do a mixed relationship. You'd want to use an overall relation of AND and put all the terms that should be related OR in one item using the IN operator. You will need to map the terms desired to their term_taxonomy_ids first.

```
$taxes = array( 'taxonomy1', 'taxonomy2', 'taxonomy3', 'taxonomy4' );

foreach ( $taxes as $tax ) {
    $terms = get_terms( $tax );

    foreach ( $terms as $term )
        $tax_map[$tax][$term->slug] = $term->term_taxonomy_id;
}


$args['tax_query'] => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'taxonomy1',
        'field' => 'term_taxonomy_id',
        'terms' => array( $tax_map['taxonomy1'][$slug] )
        'operator' => 'IN',
    ),
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'taxonomy3',
        'field' => 'term_taxonomy_id',
        'terms' => array( $tax_map['taxonomy3'][$slug] ),
        'operator' => 'IN',
    ),
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'taxonomy4', // gets ignored
        'field' => 'term_taxonomy_id',
        'terms' => array( $tax_map['taxonomy4'][$slug], $tax_map['taxonomy2'][$slug] ),
        'operator' => 'IN',
    ),
);
```

Note that pre-3.5, you'd also need to specify `'include_children' => false`. See this Trac ticket for more: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/21228

Comment: By the way, please excuse and alert me to any mistakes/inaccuracies :) Typing all this one-handed with a baby in the other.

Comment: Where does `$slug` come from...?

Comment: Just a placeholder in the code. I guess it was $term1 etc. in the original question.

Comment: You are right! This method seem to work. I will give it test, and come back to vote for this answer if it is working. Thanks

Comment: It seem the  `'taxonomy' => 'taxonomy4', // gets ignored` cannot be ignored. If i put random text in this field, no result was found. Only when I assigned real taxonomy name, it give me the result. Any idea why?

Comment: It probably checks to see if the tax exists somewhere along the line.

Comment: But from what I saw in https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/21228 and https://core.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/21552 , it shouldn't check for the taxonomy when 'term_taxonomy_id' exist, right?

Comment: After I tried many times, it still doesn't work, I think this method is not working...after i checked on the WP_TAX_QUERY Class at https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/taxonomy.php?rev=21552, I found out it's till required to check on the taxonomy name before you can use `term_taxonomy_id` for this porpuse (correct me if i am wrong), so the taxonomy name must exist in the tax_query array. Therefor, this method can't solve the problem. Any other suggest to solve this problem?

Comment: Okay, I finally wrote this up (and published it): http://10up.com/blog/wordpress-mixed-relationship-taxonomy-queries/ - basically, yes, you do have to use a valid taxonomy name, but the rest stands.

Comment: Jesus this is ridiculous that something like this isn't in the WP docs. Thanks for writing up, if the same query doesn't run for other fields as it does for `term_taxonomy_id` why the hell do they even support the former.

Answer (score 1):

I sugest using `tax_query` as the `meta_query` for multiple or/and operators like [this](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2014/10/20/update-on-query-improvements-in-4-1/)

Comment: Much better suggestion. As it was released some time after above answer.

Comment: Does meta_query allow you to filter by taxonomy? I don’t see where to specify the taxonomy type