# Tax Query only returns for the first of several terms

Tags: wp-query, custom-taxonomy, tax-query

I'm trying to query a customer post type where the results may be within one of *several* associated terms. The issue however is that only the first term `yellow-gold-jewellery` is being returned for, and all others excluded.

See my query below, by default the WP Query docs note that the `operator` on the `0` entry of my `tax_query` should be `IN`. Despite this it is only returning products in the `yellow-gold-jewellery` and neither of the latter two.

```php
{
    "posts_per_page": 9,
    "status": "publish",
    "tax_query": {
        "0": {
            "taxonomy": "jewellery_metal",
            "field": "slug",
            "terms": [
                "yellow-gold-jewellery",
                "white-gold-jewellery",
                "rose-gold-jewellery"
            ]
        },
        "1": {
            "taxonomy": "jewellery_availability",
            "field": "slug",
            "terms": [
                "sold",
                "unaccounted"
            ],
            "operator": "NOT IN"
        },
        "relation": "AND"
    },
    "per_page": "9",
    "post_type": "product"
}
```

I've tried restructuring this several ways:

1. Nesting with an OR relation separate to the top level AND
2. Removing the top level AND
3. Manually adding operator IN to object `0`

None have worked and the above seems to be exactly what is prescribed by WP docs.

I have done the obvious in checking that none of the items trip the secondary AND condition (they don't) and removing the `yellow-gold-jewellery` then defers to the `white-gold-jewellery` (and *still* not the `rose-gold-jewellery`).

It's as if it's only finding the first matched term and nothing else.

Is this how this is supposed to work? Or have I misunderstood the syntax/structure?

Comment: your query appears to be JSON not PHP, and the PHP code that takes those parameters and attempts to use them is missing. Are you sure that it's not including the other terms? Could it be they're on the next page and the `yellow-gold-jewelry` is just appearing first? Keep in mind that `NOT IN` is extremely expensive and involves copying the table so it can run the query on a temporary table in memory ( minus the bits you didn't want ). It would be much faster to list every single term in the `jewellery_availability` except those two than it would be to use `NOT IN`

Comment: I also see your first clause has no `operator` parameter, and `per_page` and `posts_per_page` are both defined

Comment: @TomJNowell it's just JSON because that's the format I've outputted it in for debugging. I appreciate the tips on performance, I'll implement them separately. Yes I am not lying, and have mentioned how I've tested multiple conditions to make sure that the yellow-gold-jewellery isn't some sticking point (querying just the last two only returning the first of the last two as well).

Comment: @TomJNowell as for the lack of operator parameter, I did mention that the WP docs lists the default as IN, I also mention that I manually included it in my testing to similarly little avail. I haven't tried removing the ..._page properties on the query, I'll see if they're the sticking point.

Comment: @TomJNowell removing the page related parts does absolutely nothing to help unfortunately.

Comment: Your tax query almost matches the docs perfectly so it's unlikely that's the issue. Can you add the code that generates these args and the code that then uses it? JSON removes context, & the issue might not be the arguments. Also how many `yellow-gold-jewelry` posts? Are you sure the problem isn't that the `rose-gold-jewelry` posts are simply not in the first 9 posts found and are on another page of the query? Afterall your query always shows page 1, and this would fit what you observed.

Comment: @TomJNowell thanks for the further suggestions, it appears the issue is that the WP docs do not specify complex AND/OR queries require to be on the `term_taxonomy_id` and no other column(s).

See here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/96338/multiple-relationship-for-multiple-tax-query-in-wp-query

My query(s) are now all functioning as expected having switched over to using that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Related issue: [Multiple relationship for multiple tax_query in WP_Query](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/96338/multiple-relationship-for-multiple-tax-query-in-wp-query)

The issue here was that mixed multi-relationship lookups are only permitted using the `term_taxonomy_ids` field in the query, the above worked fine once switched like so:

```php
$params = [
    "status" => "publish",
    "tax_query" => [
        [
            "taxonomy" => "jewellery_metal",
            "field" => "term_taxonomy_id",
            "terms" => [
                36, // "yellow-gold-jewellery"
                37, // "white-gold-jewellery"
                34, // "rose-gold-jewellery"
            ]
        ],
        [
            "taxonomy" => "jewellery_availability",
            "field" => "term_taxonomy_id",
            "terms" => [
                44, // "sold"
                49, // "unaccounted"
            ],
            "operator" => "NOT IN"
        ],
        "relation" => "AND"
    ],
    "post_type" => "product"
]
```

Annoying Wordpress Docs don't specify this, or at minimum suggest all queries are done on the `term_taxonomy_id` if it's the only one that supports all specified functionality.